# With Swagger.NET, how do I describe return values in detail?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I've got a Web API REST web service that is returning objects.  I have installed [Swagger.NET](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) as well as Swagger UI.  I'd like Swagger UI to list the fields inside of the objects being returned from the Web API REST methods.  Is this possible?

From the Swagger documentation, Swagger.NET uses ApiExplorer to gather information about the Web API endpoints I have (classes that extend ApiController).  Also, Swagger.NET looks at .NET doc comments (using '///').  I'm not sure how to describe the internals of these objects though.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported currently out of the box. Following issue is related to it. You can vote up this:
http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/877

Comment: Is there any way to comment the internals of an object returned by Swagger? I would like to have a Java client, with code generated by Swagger-Codegen.